# How can I customize Sonata Admin routes?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I have an Entity with a composite ID by 3 primary keys (one referencing another Entity in a Many-to-one relation, and 2 unique values)

I can add new records with no problem, but the issue comes here:

The link to enter to a record (show or edit) is like this: `http://localhost/app_dev.php/admin/what/ever/entity/0~0~1/edit`

Of course it doesn't work. I would like to change this pattern to something like:
`http://localhost/app_dev.php/admin/what/ever/entity/0/0/1/edit`, which pattern could be: `/admin/what/ever/entity/{key1}/{key2}/{key3}/{action}`

Any clue?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: An annotation: The code finally works (my fault)

Comment: if you found a solution by yourself, please post it as an answer so it can help other users with the same question.

Comment: Hi @PlínioCésar, I think I found an answer several months ago, but I'm not working that project anymore. So I don't know if I can rescue that answer to post it... If I could, I'll do.